# convert array to object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to convert php array to object and i want to get it in my blade.

this is my code that my array is created

```
$related_dock = DB::table('reserve')
            ->join('product_dock', 'reserve.product_id', '=', 'product_dock.product_id')
            ->join('dock', 'product_dock.dock_id', '=', 'dock.id')
            ->select([DB::raw('count(dock_id) as used'), 'dock.dock_name as dock name'])
            ->groupBy('dock_id')
            ->orderBy('used', 'desc')
            ->get();
        return $related_dock;
```

and my blade is this

```
@foreach($related_dock as $related_docks)
  {{ $related_docks }}
@endforeach
```

and this code return below array

```
Collection {#1365 ▼
 #items: array:3 [▼
   0 => {#1364 ▼
     +"used": 2
     +"dock name": "Bebek"
   }
   1 => {#1376 ▼
     +"used": 2
     +"dock name": "sisli"
   }
   2 => {#1378 ▼
     +"used": 1
     +"dock name": "Beshiktash"
   }
 ]
}
```

but i want use this array as object like this

```
@foreach($related_dock as $related_docks)
  {{ $related_docks->used }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I think it's already as it is

Comment: Bro, It's already works with no problem I think there is no need to convert

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: this is array but i want convert it to object because i want to use it in foreach like  {{ $related_docks->used }} in blade

Comment: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given. this is my error
@Tarasovych

Comment: @ArmanBagheri you should be able to access it like {{ $related_docks['used'] }}

Comment: That's because `$related_docks` inside `@foreach` is an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can do like this, please check

```
@foreach($related_dock as $key => $related_docks)
  {{ $related_docks[$key]->used }}
@endforeach
```